# Prove $\left(x^y + y^x \right)\left( \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} \right)\ge 4$

Tags: inequality

For arbitrary $x, y > 0$, prove

$$
\left(x^y + y^x \right) \left( \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} \right) \ge 4
$$

By plotting, it seems true and somewhat tight, but I cannot find a proof for it.

---

If $x\ge 1,\ y \ge 1$ or $x\le 1,\ y\le 1$, we have

$$
\left(x^y + y^x \right) \left( \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} \right)\ge \left(x^1 + y^1 \right) \left( \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} \right) \ge 4
$$

So it suffices to show the inequality for the case $0 < x < 1,\ y > 1$.

Fixing $y$, I tried

$$f(x) = \left(x^y + y^x\right) (x + y) - 4xy$$

and find that $f''(x) > 0$, so we can obtain a minimal point $x_0$ on $(0,1)$ such that $f'(x_0) = 0$. Then we need to prove $f(x_0)\ge 0$. But I have no idea for further progress.

Comment: It seems like $4$ corresponds to the absolute minimum of $(x^y+y^x)\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\right)$. Notice that for $x=y=1$, the expression is precisely $4$.

Comment: @elimpalm  I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: Maybe a place for AM/GM.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Does your solution involve examining the derivatives of (for example) $\displaystyle f(x,y) = \left(x^y + y^x\right) \times \left(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}\right)$?  If so, then if the OP (i.e. original poster) has not studied multivariable Calculus, then how is the OP supposed to show an attempt?  **To the OP**: Have you studied multivariable Calculus?  What is the source of the problem, and what is your math background?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Now I show my ideas in my edited post.

Comment: If $y=x$ the function is $4 x^{x-1}$

Comment: I also agree @ThomasAndrews. Try AM/GM inequality

Comment: @elimpalm I found a mistake in my proof for $0<x\leq1$ and $y\geq1$.

Comment: I proved it for any $0<x\leq\frac{1}{3}$ and $y\geq1$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Do you use Bernoulli's inequality ?

Comment: @Erik Satie Yes.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Maybe we need a higher order in the binomial expansion.

Comment: Where does the problem come from? The same question has been asked today: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4269107/42969.

Answer (score 5):

Using Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$(x^y + y^x)(1/y + 1/x)
\ge \left(\sqrt{\frac{x^y}{y}} + \sqrt{\frac{y^x}{x}}\right)^2.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\sqrt{\frac{x^y}{y}} + \sqrt{\frac{y^x}{x}} \ge 2. \tag{1}$$
This inequality has been proved
in [show this inequality $\sqrt{\frac{a^b}{b}}+\sqrt{\frac{b^a}{a}}\ge 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268913/show-this-inequality-sqrt-fracabb-sqrt-fracbaa-ge-2).

---

**Remark 0**: I have just noticed that @Erik Satie gave an alternative proof for (1) which is simpler than mine. See: [show this inequality $\sqrt{\frac{a^b}{b}}+\sqrt{\frac{b^a}{a}}\ge 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268913/show-this-inequality-sqrt-fracabb-sqrt-fracbaa-ge-2)

**Remark 1**: In the link (Chinese website, provided by @mengdie1982) https://www.zhihu.com/question/489824366,
qiqi1509 gave another proof for (1).

The sketch of qiqi1509's proof:

(1) is written as
$$\frac{x}{x + y}x^{(y - 1)/2} + \frac{y}{x + y} y^{(x - 1)/2}
\ge \frac{2\sqrt{xy}}{x + y}.$$

Since $u\mapsto \mathrm{e}^u$ is convex, using Jensen's inequality, we have
$$\frac{x}{x + y}x^{(y - 1)/2} + \frac{y}{x + y} y^{(x - 1)/2}
\ge \mathrm{e}^{\frac{x}{x + y}\frac{y - 1}{2}\ln x
+ \frac{y}{x + y}\frac{x - 1}{2}\ln y}.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{x}{x + y}\frac{y - 1}{2}\ln x
+ \frac{y}{x + y}\frac{x - 1}{2}\ln y
\ge \ln \frac{2\sqrt{xy}}{x + y}. \tag{2}$$

$\phantom{2}$

**Remark 2**: (2) is written as
$$\ln \frac{x + y}{2} \ge \frac{2x + (1 - x)y}{2x + 2y}\ln x
+ \frac{x + (2 - x)y}{2x + 2y}\ln y. \tag{3}$$

Perhaps, there is a simpler (or alternative) proof for (3) (with $0 < x \le 1 \le y$).

$\phantom{2}$

**Remark 3**: A similar inequality is
$$\ln \frac{x + y}{2} \ge \frac{x + 1}{2x + 2y}\ln x
+ \frac{y + 1}{2x + 2y}\ln y. \tag{4}$$
See: [Prove $2(x + y)\ln \frac{x + y}{2} - (x + 1)\ln x - (y + 1)\ln y \ge 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4277352/prove-2x-y-ln-fracx-y2-x-1-ln-x-y-1-ln-y-ge-0)

I think qiqi1509's idea works for it.