# Prove $(x^y+y^x)\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\right)\ge 4$ where $x,y>0$.

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality, optimization

Without loss of generality, we can assume $x\ge y$.

- If $x\ge y \ge 1$, then
  $$(x^y+y^x)\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\right)\ge
     (x+y)\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\right)\ge4.$$
- If $1\ge x\ge y>0$, then
  $$x^y=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{y}}=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1-x}{x}\right)^y}\ge
     \frac{1}{1+y\left(\frac{1-x}{x}\right)}=\frac{x}{x+y-xy},$$ and
  similarily $$y^x\ge\frac{y}{x+y-xy}.$$ Hence $$(x^y+y^x)\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\right)\ge \frac{\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\right)^2}{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+1}\ge 4.$$
- If $x\ge 1 \ge y>0$, how to go on?

Comment: Where does the problem come from? The same question has been asked yesterday: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4268111/42969.

Comment: I see it on a Chinese website https://www.zhihu.com/question/489824366. Someone gave an incomplete proof . @MartinR