# Prove $2(x + y)\ln \frac{x + y}{2} - (x + 1)\ln x - (y + 1)\ln y \ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, logarithms

**Problem**: Let $x, y > 0$. Prove that
$$f(x, y) = 2(x + y)\ln \frac{x + y}{2}
- (x + 1)\ln x - (y + 1)\ln y \ge 0.$$

$\phantom{2}$

**My attempt**:

For $a > 0$, we need to prove that
$$f\left(x\right)=(x+a)\ln\frac{a+x}{2}-\frac{\left(a+1\right)\ln a+\left(x+1\right)\ln x}{2} \ge 0.$$

WLOG assume that $a\leq x$

The second derivative can be rewrite as :

$$a(1-x)+x(x+1)\geq 0$$

Wich is obvious with the contraint above .

We deduce that the derivative admits a single zero and is increasing .

---

---

Edit to clarify the problem :

It's a straightforward consequence of my answer here [show this inequality $\sqrt{\frac{a^b}{b}}+\sqrt{\frac{b^a}{a}}\ge 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268913/show-this-inequality-sqrt-fracabb-sqrt-fracbaa-ge-2/4269271#4269271) in the final version .

Well after MartinR comment :I need to show it to conclude my answer .

---

---

---

---

---

### Other idea Case $0<a\leq 1$ and $x\geq a$:

Using simple bound got from https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267163352_Proofs_of_three_open_inequalities_with_power-exponential_functions lemma 7.2 where $b=0$ and $d=\frac{x+a}{2}$ we have the new function :

$$h(x)=2\left(\frac{\left(x+a\right)}{2}-1\right)-0.5\left(\left(x+1\right)\ln\left(x\right)+\left(a+1\right)\ln\left(a\right)\right)$$

It's **NOT** true that $h(x)\geq 0$ in this case . See the remarks below

Some remarks :

The derivative does not depends from $a$ .

the abscissa of the minimum of $f(x)$ denoted by $x_{min}$ is less or equal than the $x_0$ where $h(x_0)=0$ for $0<a\leq 1$ and $x\geq a$

Important remark :

It seems we have  for $0<a\leq 1$ and $x\geq a$:

$$x_{min}\leq 2-a+0.5\left(a-1\right)^{2}\leq x_{0}\quad (I)$$

It reduces the problem to a single variable inequality in $a$ .

### Some Conjectures :

Firstly It seems we have  $a\in (0,1]$:

$$0\leq f'\left(2-a+0.5\left(a-1\right)^{2}\right)$$

Secondly  It seems we have $a\in (0,1]$ :

$$0\leq h\left(2-a+0.5\left(a-1\right)^{2}\right)$$

---

---

### Question :

How to prove it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130618/discussion-on-question-by-erik-satie-prove-or-disprove-an-inequality-wich-seems).

Comment: Vasc's lemma 7.2 ...... does not work. By the way, you said "we have the new inequality", you can not say that before you prove it (unfortunately, your "new inequality" is incorrect). You should say "conjecture" "guess" etc.

Comment: @RiverLi sorry for the answer because  using convexity here is like Tantalus's punishment :-(.

Comment: @ErikSatie I edited the title and the statement of the problem (at the beginning).

Comment: @RiverLi OK that looks correct to me as edit .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem**: Let $x, y > 0$. Prove that
$$f(x, y) = 2(x + y)\ln \frac{x + y}{2}
- (x + 1)\ln x - (y + 1)\ln y \ge 0.$$

**Proof**:

Note that $f(1, 1) = 0$. We need to prove that $x = y = 1$
is the global minimizer of $f(x, y)$ on $x,y > 0$.

We have
\begin{align*}
 f(x, y) &\ge 2x \ln \frac{x}{2} + 2y\ln \frac{y}{2} - (x + 1)\ln x - (y + 1)\ln y\\
 &= (x - 1)\ln x - 2x\ln 2 + (y - 1)\ln y - 2y\ln 2. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

*Fact 1*: $(u - 1)\ln u - 2u\ln 2 > -3$ for all $u > 0$.
(The proof is given at the end.)

*Fact 2*: $(u - 1)\ln u - 2u\ln 2 > 4$ for all $u\in (0, 1/64]\cup [16, \infty)$.
(The proof is given at the end.)

By (1) and Facts 1-2, if $x < 1/64$ or $x > 16$,
then $f(x, y) > -3 + 4 = 1$,
and if $y < 1/64$ or $y > 16$,
then $f(x, y) > -3 + 4 = 1$.

Since $f(1, 1) = 0$, the minimum of $f(x, y)$ on $x, y > 0$ occurs on the region $1/64 \le x, y \le 16$.

The minimum of $f(x, y)$ on the region $1/64 \le x, y \le 16$ may occur in the interior of the region (stationary points), or it may occur on the boundary of the region.

First, we can prove that $x = y = 1$ is the only stationary point of $f(x, y)$ on $x, y > 0$:

*Fact 3*: If $x, y > 0$ satisfies
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$, then $x = y = 1$.
(The proof is given at the end.)

Second, at the boundaries of the region $1/64 \le x, y \le 16$,
it is easy to verify that $f(x, y) > 1$
using (1) and Facts 1-2.

As a result, $f(x, y) \ge 0$ for all $1/64 \le x, y \le 16$.

Thus, $f(x, y) \ge 0$ for all $x, y > 0$.

We are done.

---

---

*Proof of Fact 1*:

Let $h(u) = (u - 1)\ln u - 2u\ln 2 + 3$.
Since $(u - 1)\ln u \ge 0$ for all $u > 0$, we have $h(u) > 0$ for all
$0 < u < \frac{3}{2\ln 2}$.
If $u \ge \frac{3}{2\ln 2}$,
using $\ln 2 < \frac{4}{5}$ and $\ln z \ge \frac{2(z - 1)}{z + 1}$ for all $z \ge 1 $, we have
$$h(u)
\ge (u - 1)\cdot \frac{2(u - 1)}{u + 1} - 2u\cdot \frac{4}{5} + 3
= \frac{2u^2 - 13u + 25}{5u + 5} > 0.$$

We are done.

---

*Proof of Fact 2*:

Let $H(u) = (u - 1)\ln u - 2u\ln 2 - 4$.
We have
$H'(u) = \ln u + 1 - \frac{1}{u} - 2\ln 2$.

If $0 < u \le \frac{1}{64}$, we have
$H'(u) < 0$ and thus
$H(u) \ge H(1/64) = \frac{47}{8}\ln 2 - 4 > 0$.

If $u \ge 16$, we have
$H'(u) > 0$ and thus
$H(u) \ge H(16) =  28\ln 2 - 4 > 0$.

We are done.

---

*Proof of Fact 3*:

We have
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 2\ln\frac{x + y}{2} + 1 - \ln x  - \frac{1}{x}, \tag{2}\\
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &= 2\ln\frac{x + y}{2} + 1 - \ln y - \frac{1}{y}. \tag{3}
\end{align*}

(2) gives
$$y = -x + 2\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^{-1}x\mathrm{e}^{1/x}}. \tag{4}$$

[(2) - (3)] gives
$$\ln x + \frac{1}{x} = \ln y + \frac{1}{y}. \tag{5}$$

From (4) and (5), we have
$$\ln x + \frac{1}{x}
- \ln(-x + 2\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^{-1}x\mathrm{e}^{1/x}})  - \frac{1}{-x + 2\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^{-1}x\mathrm{e}^{1/x}}} = 0.$$

From $-x + 2\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^{-1}x\mathrm{e}^{1/x}}
> 0$, we have $\frac{1}{x}\mathrm{e}^{1/x} > \mathrm{e}/4$
which results in $0 < x < x_0$ where $x_0$ is the unique real root
of $\frac{1}{x}\mathrm{e}^{1/x} = \mathrm{e}/4$.

Let
$$g(x) = \ln x + \frac{1}{x}
- \ln(-x + 2\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^{-1}x\mathrm{e}^{1/x}})  - \frac{1}{-x + 2\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^{-1}x\mathrm{e}^{1/x}}}.$$
We have
$$g'(x) = - \frac{\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^{-1}x\mathrm{e}^{1/x}}}{x^2(-x + 2\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^{-1}x\mathrm{e}^{1/x}})^2}\cdot h(x)
- \frac{(x - 1)^2\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^{-1}x\mathrm{e}^{1/x}}}{x^2(-x + 2\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^{-1}x\mathrm{e}^{1/x}})^2} $$
where
\begin{align*}
 h(x) &= 2\sqrt{x}\,(1 - x)(\mathrm{e}^{-1/2 + 1/(2x)} - 1) + \sqrt{x}\,(1 - \sqrt{x})^2\\
 &\quad
 + 2x\sqrt{x}\left[\mathrm{e}^{1/2-1/(2x)} - 1 - \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2x}\right)\right].
\end{align*}

Since $(1 - x)(\mathrm{e}^{-1/2 + 1/(2x)} - 1) \ge 0$ for all $x > 0$,
and $\mathrm{e}^{1/2-1/(2x)} - 1 - \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2x}\right) \ge 0$
for all $x > 0$, we have $h(x) \ge 0$ for all $x > 0$.

Thus, $g'(x) < 0$ for all $x \in (0, 1)\cup (1, x_0)$. Also, $g'(1) = 0$ and $g(1) = 0$.
Thus, $g(x) = 0$ has exactly one real root, say $x = 1$.

From (4), we have $y = 1$.

We are done.

Comment: @MartinR The remaining is to check $f$ at the boundaries. Actually, you can find $a, b$ such that the minimum of $f$ occurs on $a \le x, y \le b$. So, you check the boundaries, and the stationary point.

Comment: @MartinR I found a material to help you to understand my comment. https://collegeparktutors.com/blog/finding-absolute-maximums-and-minimums-of-a-2-variable-function-on-a-closed-region

Comment: @MartinR You are right. Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me if my conjecture are correct in the OP ? Is it hard ? Can you prove it and add it in your proof ? thannnnkkkss!

Comment: @ErikSatie They are both true. I will not add this irrelevant thing in my proof.

Comment: Congrats River ! A last question can we generalised it to the Simplifire's question ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4278217/show-that-left-fracx-1x-2x-2-rightp-left-fracx-2x-3x-3-righ?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @ErikSatie I don't know.

Comment: I have my own proof now what do you think about ?

Comment: @ErikSatie You should write down clearly the detailed complete proof.

Comment: @ErikSatie You should make your proof easy to read. For example, last time, your write $k''' < 0$, but I did not see where $k$ is defined. Later I found you wrote $m\left(a\right)+m\left(2-a+0.5\left(a-1\right)^{2}\right)=k(a)=\cdots$. I think it is not nice to give the definition of $k$ in this place. I think you should write: Let $k(a) = \cdots$... We have $k''' < 0$.

Comment: @ErikSatie By the way, do you mean to prove the OP, or just the two conjectures?

Comment: both see my edits :-) .

Comment: @ErikSatie Do you prove the OP?

Comment: Yes because for $a\leq x$ the function is convex and admitts a single minimum wich I show to be greater than zero using Vasc's lemma 7.2.If you have some question I'm here .

Comment: @ErikSatie Can you elaborate on that as an answer (giving a complete detailed proof, not just two conjectures)?

Comment: @ErikSatie By the way, it is not true that $h(x) \ge 0$ (using Vasc's lemma 7.2)?

Comment: It's true on a particular interval wich is sufficient to show the inequality .

Comment: @ErikSatie If so, just write down the complete step-by-step proof clearly.

Comment: @ErikSatie I did not downvote your another answer for another topic. But I think your writing is hard to read. You should make your expression nice. For example, in $6\left(\frac{\left(a+x+c\right)}{3}-1\right)$, parentheses are not necessary, $6\left(\frac{a+x+c}{3}-1\right)$ is ok; in $\left(0.6a^{0.8}+c^{-0.2}\right)\ln\left(a\right)$, I think $\ln a$ is better than $\ln (a)$ (see Vasc's article). You should edit your expression manually.

Answer (score 2):

**Remarks**: This is to give an alternative proof of Fact 3 in my
[answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4277352/prove-2x-y-ln-fracx-y2-x-1-ln-x-y-1-ln-y-ge-0/4281996#4281996).
The new proof is related to the following three questions:
[Estimate the bound of the sum of the roots of $1/x+\ln x=a$ where $a>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725944/estimate-the-bound-of-the-sum-of-the-roots-of-1-x-ln-x-a-where-a1),
and
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2849102,
and
[Lower bound for the square root sum of the roots of $x - \ln x - m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3586321/lower-bound-for-the-square-root-sum-of-the-roots-of-x-ln-x-m).

---

**Problem**: Let $x, y > 0$. Prove that
$$f(x, y) = 2(x + y)\ln \frac{x + y}{2}
- (x + 1)\ln x - (y + 1)\ln y \ge 0.$$

**Fact 3**: If $x, y > 0$ satisfies
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$, then $x = y = 1$.

**Proof of Fact 3**:

We give the following auxiliary result.

**Lemma 1**: Let $a > 1$. The equation $\frac{1}{z} + \ln z = a$ has
two distinct real roots $z_1 < z_2$.
Then $2\ln \frac{z_1 + z_2}{2} + 1 > a$.
(The proof is given at the end.)

We have
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 2\ln\frac{x + y}{2} + 1 - \ln x  - \frac{1}{x}, \\
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &= 2\ln\frac{x + y}{2} + 1 - \ln y - \frac{1}{y}. 
\end{align*}

From $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$, we have
$$2\ln\frac{x + y}{2} + 1
= \ln x  + \frac{1}{x} = \ln y  + \frac{1}{y}. \tag{1}$$

If $x = y$, from (1), we have $x = y = 1$ (easy).

If $x \ne y$, from $\ln x  + \frac{1}{x} = \ln y  + \frac{1}{y}$, we have $\ln x + \frac{1}{x} > 1$ (easy).
However, by Lemma 1, $2\ln\frac{x + y}{2} + 1
= \ln x  + \frac{1}{x}$ is impossible.

As a result, we have $x = y = 1$.

We are done.

---

*Proof of Lemma 1*:

We use the [parametrization](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2849102) by wyz@AoPS. Let $t = z_2/z_1 > 1$. We have
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{z_1} + \ln z_1 &= a,\\
 \frac{1}{tz_1} + \ln(t z_1) &= a 
\end{align*}
which results in $\frac{1}{z_1} = \frac{1}{tz_1} + \ln t$ or
$z_1 = \frac{t - 1}{t\ln t}$.
Then we have $z_2 = \frac{t-1}{\ln t}$ and $a = \ln \frac{t - 1}{\ln t} + \frac{\ln t}{t - 1}$.

It suffices to prove that, for all $t > 1$,
$$2\ln \frac{\frac{t - 1}{t\ln t} + \frac{t-1}{\ln t}}{2} + 1 > \ln \frac{t - 1}{\ln t} + \frac{\ln t}{t - 1}$$
or
$$h(t) := 2\ln\frac{1+t}{2t} + \ln \frac{t - 1}{\ln t} + 1 - \frac{\ln t}{t - 1} > 0.$$
We have
\begin{align*}
 h'(t) &= \frac{(t^2 + t)\ln^2 t + (t - 1)^3\ln t - (t + 1)(t - 1)^2}{t(1 + t)(t - 1)^2\ln t}\\[6pt]
 &> \frac{(t^2 + t)\cdot \frac{2(t - 1)}{t + 1}\cdot\ln t + (t - 1)^3\ln t - (t + 1)(t - 1)^2}{t(1 + t)(t - 1)^2\ln t} \tag{2}\\[6pt]
 &= \frac{t^2 + 1}{2t(t^2 - 1)\ln t}\left(\ln (t^2) - \frac{2(t^2 - 1)}{t^2 + 1}\right)\\[6pt]
 &> 0 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
where we have used
$\ln t > \frac{2(t-1)}{t + 1}$
for all $t > 1$ in (2) and (3).
Also, we have $\lim_{t\to 1^{+}} h(t) = 0$. Thus, we have $h(t) > 0$ for all $t > 1$.

We are done.

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks that nice I have also a second proof can you show for $x,y\in(0,\infty)$ and $x\neq y$ : $$\left(x+1\right)\ln\left(x\right)<\left(x+y\right)\ln\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)+\frac{\left(1+x+y\right)}{x+2y}\left(x-y\right)$$ ?

Comment: @ErikSatie I have no idea.

Comment: @RiverLi Woopsie it's false ...Try : $$\left(x+1\right)\ln x<\left(x+y\right)\ln\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)+\left(x-y\right)+\frac{\left(x-y\right)^{3}}{12\left(x+y\right)^{2}}$$ for $x,y>0,x\neq y$ . Remains to add the two inequalities .

Comment: @ErikSatie I believe it is true. Very nice. It is some kind of isolate fudging. If you can prove it nicely, then your proof is very nice.

Answer (score -1):

---

---

---

First conjecture :

Define :

$$F(x)=f'(x)$$

We have $a\in(0,1)$ :

$$F(2-a+0.5\left(a-1\right)^{2})=\ln\left(a+2-a+0.5\left(a-1\right)^{2}\right)-\frac{0.5}{2-a+0.5\left(a-1\right)^{2}}-0.5\ln\left(2-a+0.5\left(a-1\right)^{2}\right)+0.5-\ln\left(2\right)$$

Using differentiation we have :

$$(F(2-a+0.5\left(a-1\right)^{2}))'=\frac{\left(a^{5}-10a^{4}+40a^{3}-74a^{2}+63a-20\right)}{\left(a^{2}-4a+5\right)^{2}\left(a^{2}-2a+5\right)}=\frac{\left(a-1\right)^{2}\left(a^{3}-8a^{2}+23a-20\right)}{\left(a^{2}-4a+5\right)^{2}\left(a^{2}-2a+5\right)}<0$$

We are done !

---

---

---

Second conjecture :

We need to show for $x\in(0,1]$ :

$$p(x)=(x-1)^2-(x+1)\ln(x)-(2-x+0.5(x-1)^2+1)\ln(2-x+0.5(x-1)^2)\geq 0$$

The second derivative is :

$$p''(x)=\frac{-\left(-2x^{2}+8x-6\right)}{\left(x^{2}-4x+5\right)^{2}}+\frac{\left(1-x\right)}{x^{2}}+\frac{2}{\left(x-4\right)x+5}-\ln\left(\left(0.5x-2\right)x+2.5\right)-1$$

Now we use the bound $z\in[1,3]$:

$$k(x)=\frac{0.5\left(z^{2}-1\right)}{z}\geq \ln(z)$$

Remains to show :

$$\frac{-\left(-2x^{2}+8x-6\right)}{\left(x^{2}-4x+5\right)^{2}}+\frac{\left(1-x\right)}{x^{2}}+\frac{2}{\left(x-4\right)x+5}-k\left(\left(0.5x-2\right)x+2.5\right)-1\geq 0$$

Wich is smooth using a computer .

So now as conclusion we have showed that the minimum is greater than zero because the abscissa of the minimum of $f(x)$ is less or equal than the root of $h(x)$ .

Comment: @RiverLi can you check my progress ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: See my comment on the OP. Please edit or delete this part in the OP (for example, emphasize $h(x)\ge 0$ is not true for $0 < a \le 1, x\ge 1$): **Other idea Case 0<a≤1 and x≥1** "...lemma 7.2 where ... we have the new function..."

Comment: You can use \tag{something} to label the equation. For example, \tag{V} for your first equation: $0\leq h\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{\left(x-1\right)\left(x+1\right)}{2}}\right) \tag{V}$

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks for the help :-)!

Comment: Why did you say you "I show the hardest part I mean"? If so, you do have a complete proof? I think that the part you does not prove is your hardest part.

Comment: You said "We have $x \in (0,25, 1]$ ...", do you mean you have proved it? Or you just want to prove it? Do you say "we have" unless you have proved it.

Comment: In the OP, $f(x, a)$ is symmetric, you may assume $x \ge a$. However, you discuss two cases (not necessary): (1) $0 < a \le 1$, $x \ge 1$; (2) $a \ge 1$ and $0 < x \le 1$. You may edit it.

Comment: By the way, I did not downvote you.

Comment: @RiverLi Again thanks !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130763/discussion-between-erik-satie-and-river-li).

Comment: You just comment here.

Comment: In the 2nd line, you can not say "We have" before you prove it. You should make clear what you have proved. Also, you should separate different parts using <hr> etc. This makes easy reading.

Comment: $m\left(a\right)+m\left(2-a+0.5\left(a-1\right)^{2}\right)=k(a)=\cdots$, I think it is not nice to put the definition of $k(a)$ here. Perhaps it is better to "Let $k(a) = \cdots$".

Comment: Actually, 
$$ h\left(2-a+0.5\left(a-1\right)^{2}\right)
= m(a)+m\left(2-a+0.5\left(a-1\right)^{2}\right) = k(a).$$
It is not necessary to use all $h, m, k$.
For example, directly $[h\left(2-a+0.5\left(a-1\right)^{2}\right)]''' < 0$ without introducing $m(a), k(a)$,
or let $k(a) = h\left(2-a+0.5\left(a-1\right)^{2}\right)$, then $k'''(a) < 0$.

Comment: By $f'(2-a+0.5\left(a-1\right)^{2})$, do you mean $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Big\vert_{x = 2-a+0.5\left(a-1\right)^{2}}$, or $[f(2-a+0.5\left(a-1\right)^{2})]'$?

Comment: I mean $b(x)=f'(x)$ then $b(2-a+0.5(a-1)^2)=f'(2-a+0.5(x-1)^2)$

Comment: I think, you may write: Let $F(a) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Big\vert_{x = 2-a+0.5\left(a-1\right)^{2}}$ (something like that). Then $F'(a) = \cdots$ (replace $(f'(2-a+0.5\left(a-1\right)^{2}))'$).